# Can't add serial code/activate VMware

Tags: vmware-workstation

I download latest VMware Workstation form VMW page, and install it in Ubuntu 13.04. When i run VMW it ask me for activation, so I click "Enter Licence Key" but nothings happen so I can't run machines. Even after restart. Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell

Comment: Since VMware is proprietary third party software, you will have to seek support from them.

Comment: /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx --new-sn XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXX

Answer (score 25):

Open up terminal and use this command.
replace INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE with serial number provided to you by vmware

```
sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx --new-sn INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

Comment: You deserve as many +1's as can be given, sir.

Answer (score 2):

For VMware Workstation 9 - you can run:

```
    sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-enter-serial
```

and enter serial into popup

Comment: I've been waiting for entering the serial. Thank you very much.I will try and let you know.